# Dynamical system output - differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am applying at a Faculty for Electrical Engineering, and I have an entrance exam in two days. I have few exams for exercise, from previous years and I keep getting stuck in one particular type of problem:

"A dynamicaI system is described by a differential equation of the following form:
$$y''(t) + 5y'(t)+4y(t) = u(t)$$
where t is the independent variable of time, $u(t)$ is the input signal into the system, and $y(t)$ is the system response."

I need to prove that if the system is excited with stepped amplitude signal of $1$, the output of the system in the steady state will reach a constant value of $0.25$.

Can anyone please suggest how can I solve this problem. I think I should use Laplace Transformation to solve it, but I do not know to how transform the above differential equation in some type that can be solved with Laplace. Also, i do not get where does the amplitude signal of $1$ is used.

Any help or hints are welcomed and appreciated, I need all the help I can get.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this would suit [ELECTRICAL ENGINEERING.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) better?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I did not know there is a page for Electrical Engineering. I will try there.

Comment: The question definitely belongs to math.SE. To solve this, why not use that every solution of the differential equation is $$y(t)=ae^{-t}+be^{-4t}+\frac13e^{-t}\int_0^tu(s)e^sds-\frac13e^{-4t}\int_0^tu(s)e^{4s}ds$$ for some constants $(a,b)$ depending on the initial conditions $(y(0),y'(0))$, and plug in the function $u(t)$ you are interested in, whatever it is? For instance, if $u(t)=1$ for every $t>0$, one gets a fully explicit formula for $y(t)$, from which the limit when $t\to\infty$ is direct...

Comment: An electrical engineer would probably do Laplace tranformation $$(s^2+5s+4)Y=\frac{1}{s}$$ then do the partial fractions, solve the system and ensure that the limit is as expected. Or maybe use the [final value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem) instead if allowed.

Comment: I started solving it like that and ended with $$Y=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{3}e^{-t}+\frac{1}{12}e^{-4t}$$ , and I am stuck again.

Comment: @mchingoska Correct (except for that it is $y(t)$, not $Y(s)$). Now take the limit when $t\to +\infty$. Does it go to the steady state $1/4$?

Comment: @А.Г. Well when $t\to \infty$, then all exponential values in the above equation are equal to $0$. So I guess I am left with the limit of $\frac{1}{4}$, or when I divide $0.25$ (the result I need). Can you please just explain why do I need to find the limit when $t\to \infty$ ? Is it because it is a steady state?

Comment: @mchingoska A [steady state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steady_state) is a state that nothing happens to the system at. An equilibrium. In this case,  $y(t)=\text{const}$. An aedonist has shown that it is $1/4$. Then you have to prove that the output does, indeed, go to it as $t\to\infty$. One way is to calculate the output and to take the limit. Anyhow, the behaviour as $t\to\infty$ is that of interest.

Comment: @A.Γ. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question you do not actually need to solve the differential equation. 
Indeed, in steady state conditions both $y´´$ and $y´$ will vanish: hence you are (asymptotically) left with the equation $$ 4 y(t) = 1$$ (as $u(t)$ is where the step input function comes into play) from which one concludes $$ y = 1/4 = 0.25$$

Comment: **Assuming** there is a steady state...

Comment: @Did, needless to say you are right. I was just wondering  if the existence of a steady state was in some way implied by the question formulation itself, which I believe the OP adapted from the exam sheet, "I need to prove that if the system is excited with stepped amplitude signal of 1 , the output of the system in the steady state will reach a constant value of 0.25"

Comment: Yes, the steady state was given in the question formulation. I did not know that in steady state the condition y'' and y' vanish. @An aedonist, your answer helped me a lot, thank you very much.

Comment: @Did The steady state is clearly to exist after it has been calculated as $y(t)=1/4$. What I think is important here to add is that the steady state is, in fact, *stable*, so the output will asymptotically reach it as questioned and does not diverge.

Comment: @A.Γ. Right, I meant "assuming the solution converges to a steady state" (which seems to be assumed from the start, for reasons I cannot fathom since one can easily *prove* it).

Comment: @mchingoska, glad I could help, all the best for your exam

Comment: The steady state is defined as the $t\rightarrow\infty$ limit of the particular integral, the particular integral of this equation is just $1/4$ (with $u(t)=1$). So, in general, the above approach is invalid but yields the correct solution in this particular case

Comment: @Kiryl Pesotski, I am unsure I understand why the approach is invalid, could you please clarify? I would be grateful if, for example, you exhibited an example where the invalid approach yields a wrong answer.

Comment: Let $u(t)=e^{-i\omega{t}}$, the particular intgral is $y_{p}(t)=\frac{e^{-i\omega{t}}}{4-5i\omega-\omega^{2}}$, the steady state $y_{s}=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}y_{p}(t)=\frac{1}{4-5i\omega-\omega^{2}}$, in the particular case $\omega=0$, we recover the original equation and answer is $1/4$. Is it clear?

Comment: @Kiryl Pesotski, that is clear indeed, yet I disagree with your downvote. We were dealing specifically with the case $u(t) = H(t)$ as posed by the OP, where $H(t)$ stands for the step function, and I never claimed any more generality.

Comment: @KirylPesotski If you feed in the harmonic signal $e^{i\omega t}$ you will get your output $y_p(t)$ as a harmonic oscillation with no existing limit as $t\to\infty$. Your $y_s$ is not a steady state, but an amplitude (frequency response at $\omega$). I do not see your point.

Comment: Yes, you're right, let it be $e^{-\lambda{t}}$, the particular integral $y_{p}=\frac{e^{-\lambda{t}}}{\lambda^{2}-5\lambda+4}$, thus $y_{s}=\frac{1}{\lambda^{2}-5\lambda+4}$. Sorry i've mistaken as wanted to quickly make the point...

Comment: in the harmonic case, the steady state solution does not exist!